# /privileges/trusted-user does not explain the additional privileges

Tags: bug, reputation, privileges

[`/privileges/trusted-user`](https://superuser.com/privileges/trusted-user) does not explain how to best apply the *delete answers* privilege.

---

Here's a little comparison. First, I quote *access to moderator tools* privileges explanation for *deleting questions* (it says *Deleting posts* in the title, but that's apparently not precise):

> ### Deleting posts
>
> #### When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check that there are no good answers — if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!
>
> Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as duplicates — they can serve as a signpost, directing users to useful answers on another question.
>
> It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers.
>
> You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for trusted users. If you feel a post should be deleted despite having lots of votes or for being new, please flag it for community moderator attention.
>
> You can view a list of posts with outstanding delete votes via the moderator tools delete tab.

---

Here's the explanation in the *trusted user* privileges page:

> ### What are trusted users?
>
> Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including:
>
> *Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower*

That's *really* all there is about this. The rest of the page goes on about *what tag wikis are*. If you managed to get 20k+ reputation and don't know what they are, you're probably doing it wrong.

But it says *absolutely nothing* about when it is appropriate to *delete answers*.

As a long-time user, I am familiar with closing questions, and that's an indicator a question isn't good. With the additional explanation on the question deletion privilege, I have an idea how to act.

But deleting answers? I have *no idea* what answers need to be deleted. Except maybe those I flag as spam or offensive, but is this all we should use this for?

---

This is a bug report against the user documentation.

Comment: It's even lacking explanation on when to delete *questions*. But yes, it doesn't make sense to vote to delete an answer when it's obviously spam / not an answer anyway and should therefore be flagged.

Comment: Uhm. Who would vote to close as *off topic*?

Comment: Tom [reposted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/can-the-privileges-page-for-trusted-users-list-answer-deletion-guidelines) this to MSO and received an answer that apparently is also valid for *answers*, even though not explicitly mentioned. I withdraw this bug report.

Comment: I still consider this insufficiently answered. A complete lack of guidelines just calls for problems. At least one sentence … Oh well.